# How to create queryset expression containing different types

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have two models like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    expires_in_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=20)


class Item(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

And I need to determine which items I should set expired:

```
items_to_cancel = Item.objects.annotate(expires_date=F('created') + F('category__expires_in_days'))\
                             .filter(expires_date__lte=timezone.now().date())
```

Running this query raises an exception:

```
FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.
```

**UPDATE**

After I updated the query to

```
items_to_cancel = Item.objects.annotate(expires_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('created') + F('category__expires_in_days'), output_field=DateField()))\
                             .filter(expires_date__lte=timezone.now().date())
```

I got this exception:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer.
```

So now I can't figure out how I can get date from timestamp.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman for his comment about ExpressionWrapper. But I had to make one more update to make it work, I had to apply `TruncDate` function to the timestamp:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

items_to_cancel = Item.objects.annotate(
        expires_date=ExpressionWrapper(
            TruncDate('created') + F('category__expires_in_days'),
            output_field=DateField()
        )
    ).filter(expires_date__lte=timezone.now().date())
```

Comment: I hope the code is more readable after the editing. Personally I don't use the backslashes as line endings. If it isn't at your taste, you can revert the changes.